# agrupar colunas no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tem esses insert na tabela
[image: tabela partidas]

gostaria de um sql me retorna-se os total de pontos da equipe tipo:

time - pontos

uruguai - 9

russia - 6

arabia - 3

egito - 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se isso te atende:

```
with pontuacao_times as(
select time1       as time
      ,pontostime1 as pontos
  from Sua_tabela
union all
select time2       as time
      ,pontostime2 as pontos
  from Sua_tabela)
select time
      ,pontos 
  from pontucao_times
 group by time, pontos;
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Por nada, você chegou a testar minha resposta? Funciou?

Answer (score 2):

Este código resolve:

```
SELECT TIME, SUM(J.PONTOS) AS PONTOS FROM (
   SELECT TIME1 AS TIME, PONTOSTIME1 AS PONTOS
      FROM JOGOS
   UNION ALL
   SELECT TIME2 AS TIME, PONTOSTIME2 AS PONTOS
      FROM JOGOS) AS J
GROUP BY TIME
ORDER BY PONTOS DESC
```

Resulta em:

```
TIME    PONTOS
uruguai 9
russia  6
arabia  3
egito   0
```

Veja funcionando em http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/292934/25

Comment: muito obrigado funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Obrigado. Para ajudar o site, por favor marque a opção 'aceite' (ícone de 'confere' abaixo da pontuação da resposta)